# TableView cell messing up constraints

Tags: iphone, swift, uitableview

I've a tableView where I present news feed from my Database. The amount of cells right now is around 20 but it will continue to grow for sure.

In a cell I've three labels: Title, Date and a short description. I've set up all of my constraints using storyboards. And the height of my tableView cell is dynamically changing according to the size of my content.

The problem is whenever I load my feed, one of the cells is always messed up. There is a constraint between Title label and date label >=30 so it's always at least one cell that will have a title label with a constant width of 190 (the others are always correctly displayed). If I scroll my tableView up and return back to that cell it will come back to normal but the height of the cell will stay the same (too big for the content).

[image: This is how it looks on the first load]
[image: This is how it looks if I scroll down to the end of the tableView and back]

What can be causing the problem?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

[image: This is how it looks in storyboard]
[image: The >= part is set to 30]

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {




    //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FinalNews

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 237/255, blue: 229/255, alpha: 1)

    let chevron = UIImage(named: "Next4.png")
    cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
    cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: chevron!)

    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    // Feeds dictionary.
    var dict : NSDictionary! = myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary

    let firstiteration: String = (myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("Description")?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<b>", withString: ""))!
    let seconditeration = firstiteration.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<[^>]+>", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)


    let category: String = myFeed[indexPath.row].objectForKey("CategoryID") as! String

    func getCategory(value: String) -> String {
        var end = value.endIndex
        for var i = value.startIndex;
            i < value.endIndex;
            i = i.successor() {
                if value[i] == "\n" {
                    end = i
                    break
                }

        }
        return value[value.startIndex..<end]
    }


    let counter1 = getCategory(category)

    if counter1 == "1"{
        cell.titleLabel.text = myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("DosNum") as? String
        cell.descLabel.text = " \n "
        cell.descLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 237/255, blue: 229/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.dateLabel.text = myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("Date_text") as? String
    }
    else{

        cell.titleLabel.text = myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("Title") as? String
        cell.descLabel.text = seconditeration
        cell.descLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.dateLabel.text = myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("Date_text") as? String

    }

    var shorDate: String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
    }
    let today1 = shorDate
    let dateIter = myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("Date_publication") as? String

    let dateIter1: String = (dateIter as? NSString)!.substringToIndex(10)

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()


    //let twoDaysAgo = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -1, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
    var shorDate1: String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        let oneDaysAgo = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -1, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(oneDaysAgo!)
    }

    let oneDaysAgo1 = shorDate1


    if today1 == dateIter1{
        cell.dateLabel.text = "Сегодня"
        //someDate is berofe than today
    } else if dateIter1 == oneDaysAgo1 {
        //someDate is equal or after than today
        cell.dateLabel.text = "Вчера"
    } else {
        cell.dateLabel.text = myFeed.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("Date_text") as? String
    }

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Without sharing a screen of IB or the code respectively you will harldy get good answers.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I've updated my question.

Comment: Yoru title label is too small and you don't have the constraints to enlarge it dynamically. Try sticking its right edge to the left edge of the date label.

Comment: I've already done that. DateLabel.Leading >= TitleLabel.Trailing + 30 The problem is sometimes TableView cell TitleLabel is messed up for one random cell (like on those screenshots in my question) and on rare occasions everything is fine.

Comment: In both cases DateLabel.Leading IS >= TitleLabel.Trailing + 30. Try it with <= or turn them around.

Comment: Figured this out, I've just set up custom width for TitleLabel for every type of device. It's a crappy workaround but it's the only way it has worked for me.